# How to make a file open in text-editor if no default application is selected?

Tags: ventura, defaults, text-editor

I use files with various extensions, some of which are even prefixed, like "c3.filename", "s.filename", etc. On clicking a file, I want it to open in my default text editor (emacs) if no specific application is selected. As of now, I have to select open-with on right-click every time I want to open the file in the text editor. I could not a find a satisfactory answer for it in the questions/answers posted earlier for extensionless files and using automator.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Your question appears to have answers in both scenarios (no extension and unknown extensions). In your edit you contradict the first part of the question - stating that it has arbitrary extensions and then asserting that they don't have extensions. Maybe if you clear that up and explain why the suggested answers are not satisfactory your question may be reopened.

Comment: The answers to the question linked on top are the best you can get. The first one basically asks the same as you do here (at least I read "Is it possible that all files with unknown extension can be automatically opened with a default application like Sublime Text?" the same as "On clicking a file, I want it to open in my default text editor (emacs) if no specific application is selected.")